# Откуда пошло выражение "мы с тобой"

Tags: синтаксис, история

Многие люди разговаривая с одним собеседником говорят "мы с тобой".

Если до сих пор не понятно, объясню подробно:
Стоят два человека, и один из них говорит: "Мы с тобой...".
Местоимением "мы" он уже называет, как минимум двух людей,
а местоимением "тобой" на третьего.
Но их всего двое.
Поэтому я хочу узнать откуда это пошло.

Comment: Нет третьего,  он лишь уточнеят, кто входит в "мы".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

«С тобой» — уточнение, и варианты встречаются разные: мы с тобой, с ним , с ними ,с ней, поэтому ничего лишнего здесь нет.